# Find all files containing two patterns

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to find all files that contain 2 specific strings. It needs to match both string1 AND string2. What I've tried so far:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -lie 'string1' -lie 'string2' {} \;
```

But this seems to find string1 OR string2. How can I find all files containing both string1 AND string2?

In this specific case, I'm trying to find all documents that contain both strings 'sed' and 'lynx'

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -lie 'sed' -lie 'lynx' {} \;
```

Comment: Are they on same line?

Comment: More than likely they are not on the same line but it is possible in some cases.

Comment: A minimal input and output with all the cases you want to cover would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do, even when the strings are not on the same line:

`find ~ -type f -name \*.txt -exec grep -iq string1 \{\} \; -exec grep -iq string2 \{\} \; -print`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` as below to match both the patterns.

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -iE 'string1.*string2|string2.*string1' {} +
```

Notice the `{} +` to apply the `grep` comamnd on all the files in one-shot, rather than invoking multiple processes.