# How do I find all files that contain two keywords in a file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

UPDATE: So I know this can be done with grep outside of IntelliJ IDE but within the IDE how is it done?

This is exactly the same question as mine except it is outside Intellij and there is a way to do this with grep:

I could grep it using the following answer but this would be done outside the IDE search function find in files.

[Find all files containing two patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546709/find-all-files-containing-two-patterns)

I want to find all files in an my Intellij project that container two keywords.

I am using Intellij on a Java Spring project and I am trying to locate all controllers that are used to support a given URL Path.  The way the code is written in one part of the file you have the base and in another you have the last part of of the url. For example:

```
  /abc/defg/hijk is my rest endpoint.
```

but in controller it gets split up into:

```
    /abc/defg line 5


   /hijk     // line 25
```

So to get this file I need to be able to return the files that contain both strings /hijk and /abc/defg

I cannot just search on one of them.

Comment: **Mod Note:** no need for more discussion here. There's a lot of flags and the discussion is getting emotional. When this happens, please all parties disengage.

Comment: This post currently being discussed on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390186/8239061

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Search for the first string using `Find in Path`
2. Click on the `Open in Find Window` button
3. Search for the other string '/abc/defg' using `Find in Path` with, and this is the important part, the scope `Files in Previous Search Result` selected

This will limit the search to the files in the open search result window.