# How do I find all files that contain two keywords in a file in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

My question is a follow up question on the selected answer for [How do I find all files that contain two keywords in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970135/how-do-i-find-all-files-that-contain-two-keywords-in-a-file)

Step 1: Search for the first string using Find in Path

Step 2: Click on the Open in Find Window button

Step 3: Search for the other string '/abc/defg' using Find in Path with, and this is the important part, the scope Files in Previous Search Result selected.

Below is what I see:

Step 1: search use 'Find in path' for 'math'

[image]

Step 2: clicking 'open in find window'

[image]

Step 3: doing another 'Find in path' for 'cost'

[image]

I am not seeing 'the scope Files in Previous Search Result selected' at all. Step 3 is just bring up the exact UI as step 1.

I am using community version 2021.1, but I am quite sure it's not the version but my operation. What can I try next?

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with scope dropdown opened?

Comment: @y.bedrov in which step? i am not sure where is the 'scope dropdown' in any of the steps, that's my main problem. could you attach a screenshot of the 'scope/scope dropdown'?

Comment: In your screen shot of the Find in Path popup in step 3, under the text field, are 4 buttons: "In Project", "Module", "Directory" and "Scope". Click on "Scope" and select "Files in Previous Search Result" in the dropdown that appears.

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers thanks, man! finally got it. how dumb i was.